# I want the title to = the filename

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using a plugin called inpost galleries and it uses stackoverflow.  I want to force the title that appears below the image to be the name of the image rather than a title I have given it.  Please see the site below if you have any suggestions.

I saw this code in a similar post but couldn't figure out how to use it.

```
<?=basename($image->filename, '.jpg')?>
```

If you have any suggestions, please let me know.  Really new to jquery and php files.   I know a little html, but all the $ and -> and echo's are really confusing to me.

Thanks in advance.

Oh yea, here is the link to the website, its a personal blog.

http://www.kiwiapples.com/maldives/

Comment: You can [edit] your question add the link directly into your question.

Comment: You are using a plugin that "uses stackoverflow"? What do you mean?

Comment: Can you write the desired HTML and your PHP code as it is now?  The HTML you mention in your comment isn't valid.

Comment: Site takes more than 1 second to load, you have bigger problems than figuring out basename.

Comment: @MrJack Not everyone needs to have a page speed goal of 1 second.  Consider that for a personal blog site, content quality might be more important.

Comment: Well he has no speed goal, I'm not gonna sit around waiting for it to load to try and decode what he is trying to say.

Comment: That is true, thank you, but I am also trying to fix that.  It is really just for friends and family right now, but in the future hope to make it a place for travelers to visit for info, and that being said, need it to load quicker too!

Comment: Also, jQuery isn't defined everywhere on that site, just so you know. You probably want to include the proper `<script>` element with specified source somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The code is PHP, not HTML. `<?= ?>` means "echo the result" or "output the result to the page", the `->` means that `filename` is a property of the object `$image`. The `$` denotes a variable in PHP.

You can use:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('$image->filename');
$title = path_parts['filename'];
```

Comment: Alright, so here goes my super newbie coming out, but where do I put that.  It is a wordpress site and I went to the editor and there were many files to edit.

This is a screen shot of the all the editors/files??

http://www.kiwiapples.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Screenshot-of-editor-for-inpost-galleryJPG.jpg

Comment: Also, I tried to find my exact .php, but couldn't upload it on here, so here is someone elses that is exact same.

https://github.com/wp-plugins/inpost-gallery/blob/master/index.php